# Increasing the speed of a Pandas function with Numba Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, numba

I am trying to implement `numba` to the panda series below to make the computation faster. However it does not work and gives me an error. What could I do to speed up the `std` and `ym` function calculations.

```
FILE = 'input.csv'
data =pd.read_csv(FILE, low_memory=False)
#reverses all the table data values
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
#Columns
PC_list= np.array(data1['Close'])
number = 10000
@njit
def values():
    #standard deviation (std) and ymean (ym) calculation
    std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
    ym = pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).mean().dropna().to_numpy()
    return std , ym
var= values()
```

Input csv Output:

```
[386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63
 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63
 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 373.   370.69
 370.13 370.13 369.73 369.73 375.41 375.41 375.41 375.   375.   375.
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.94
 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52
 376.52 376.52 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32
 370.96 370.96 370.96 377.09 377.09 377.09 377.09 378.97 374.39 374.4 ]
```

Comment: Numba doesn't work with pandas. You can read up more in the official docs.

Comment: It says that you could implement pandas in this article so I tried it: https://medium.com/swlh/6-ways-to-significantly-speed-up-pandas-with-a-couple-lines-of-code-part-1-2c2dfb0de230

Comment: Well, then you are using a wrong decorator. The article talks about `@vectorize` decorator, not `@njit` and the latter does not work with pandas.

Comment: Also official docs don't mention Pandas when talking about `@vectorize` decorator, only about Numpy ufuncs. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html